# Route param is getting weird

Tags: angularjs, http, firefox, resources

I have few routes in which i add token or id dynamically on user actions.
so the issue is dynamic params is turning weird and causing problem for my backend. some of buggy url mention below

1. `/feedback/:token` which changes to `/feedback?token=%7B%7BcurrentSharingImage%7D%7D`
   this is the code which is causing this issue

   ```
   Feedback.get({token: $routeParams.token})
   .$promise
   .then(feedback => {
     $scope.feedbackDetails = feedback;
     // remaining code
   });
   ```
2. `/download-file/:id` which changes to `/download-files/{{currentSharingImage}}`

   ```
   DownloadFile.getOne({id: $routeParams.id})
   .$promise       
   .then((fileRequest) => {
   }).catch(()=>{
     $scope.control.isLoading = false;   
     Alert.errorToast('Error getting file.');
   });
   ```
3. `/hub-admin/manual-messaging/:id` which changes to `/hub-admin/manual-messaging/{{currentSharingImage}}`

There are many URLs but I have came across this.

I am using angular 1.5.8 and specifically issue is with FireFox. Can I get some clue what is causing this issue?

Comment: can you show the state declaration, esperially the params definition of "token" please?

Comment: for case 1 in my routes file i have 
{
    path: '/feedback/:token',
    templateUrl: 'modules/feedback/feedback.html',
    controller: 'FeedbackCtrl'
}